# Alfresco: get user of complete task

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I need help with getting user on event task complete, which completed task, if is member of assignee group, but is not claimed task, only finished task. 
(nobody of assignee group claimed task).

When task is complete in JScript, I print variable:

bpm_assignee is null
initiator.properties.userName is owner workflow

I want get user of completed task, which is member of assignee group and ended task.

Answer (score 0):

With below SQL you can get completed task details from alfresco repository.

```
SELECT a.id_, a.name_, a.description_, a.actorid_, a.create_, a.end_, a.duedate_, b.stringvalue_  
FROM jbpm_taskinstance a, jbpm_variableinstance b  
WHERE a.end_ is not null AND a.isopen_= false AND b.taskinstance_= a.id_ AND b.name_ = 'bpm_outcome' AND a.end_ > CURRENT_DATE AND b.stringvalue_= 'Process'
```

You can find a group once you have actor id.